# Can't print out text from textbox with threads.

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, tcp, tcpserver

Can't figure out how to update the textbox from a thread. Any ideas? Sorry if the variable names and string are in Norwegian. Can fix if its a problem.
The problem is mainly that I can't acces the textbox from within the thread. Do I create separate threads, one for the server and one for updating the txtbox? In that case, how do I do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace SentralGUI.Pages
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for Server.xaml
   /// </summary>




public partial class Server : UserControl
{
    public class Bruker
    {
        public string BrukerID { get; set; }
        public string Passord { get; set; }
        public string Forbruk { get; set; }

    }
    public class ServerStart
    {
        public List<Bruker> brukerList { get; set; }
        int n = 3;
        int n_login = 5;
        int recv, recvID, recvP;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        string mottattKundeID;
        string mottattPassord;
        string consoleText = "";


        public string TxtUt()
        {

            return consoleText;

        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Socket lytteSokkel = new Socket(
                                        AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                        SocketType.Stream,
                                        ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IPEndPoint serverEP = new IPEndPoint(
                                        IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);

            lytteSokkel.Bind(serverEP);
            lytteSokkel.Listen(10);



            while (n-- > 0)
            {
                consoleText = "venter på en klient...";


                Socket kommSokkel = lytteSokkel.Accept(); // blokkerende 
                // metode

                IPEndPoint klientEP =
                                    (IPEndPoint)kommSokkel.RemoteEndPoint;
                consoleText = "Har forbindelse med {0} på port {1}" +
                                            klientEP.Address + serverEP.Port;


                string startup = "Login med kunde ID og passord:";
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(startup);
                kommSokkel.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                while (n_login > 0)
                {
                    kommSokkel.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\nBruker ID: "));

                    data = new byte[1024];
                    recvID = kommSokkel.Receive(data);
                    if (recvID == 0)
                        break;

                    mottattKundeID =
                                        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recvID);//her kommer input fra klient: BrukerID

                    kommSokkel.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Passord: "));

                    recvP = kommSokkel.Receive(data);
                    mottattPassord = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recvP);//her kommer input fra klient: Passord





                    bool godkjent_Login = Login(mottattKundeID, mottattPassord, brukerList);



                    if (godkjent_Login)
                    {
                        kommSokkel.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\nGodkjent innlogging! Trykk en tast for å få ditt forbruk.\n"));
                        string kundeForbruk = SkrivUtForbruk(mottattKundeID, brukerList);
                        kommSokkel.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(kundeForbruk));
                        n_login = 0;
                    }
                    else kommSokkel.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\nBruker ID eller passord er feil! Prøv igjen."));
                }
                consoleText = "Forbindelsen med {0} er brutt " +
                                                         klientEP.Address;

                n_login = 5;
                kommSokkel.Close();
            }

            lytteSokkel.Close();


        }
        private static string SkrivUtForbruk(string kundeID, List<Bruker> bruker)
        {
            string forbrukUT = "";
            foreach (Bruker kunde in bruker)
            {
                if (kunde.BrukerID.Contains(kundeID)) forbrukUT = kunde.Forbruk;
            }

            return forbrukUT;
        }
        private static bool Login(string id, string pass, List<Bruker> bl)
        {

            bool godkjent = false;


            //var brukerLogin = new List<BrukerLogin>();
            //brukerLogin.Add(new BrukerLogin { BrukerIDInn = id , PassordInn = pass });
            foreach (Bruker kunde in bl)
            {
                if (kunde.BrukerID == id && kunde.Passord == pass) godkjent = true;
            }
            // Console.WriteLine(bl_godkjent);
            //if (brukerID_godkjent) godkjent = true;
            return godkjent;

        }


    }



    public Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtConsol.IsEnabled = false;



    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnServerStart.IsEnabled = false;

        var brukerList = new List<Bruker>();
        brukerList.Add(new Bruker { BrukerID = "13", Passord = "iamlorde", Forbruk = "6KW" });
        brukerList.Add(new Bruker { BrukerID = "14", Passord = "iamlorde", Forbruk = "5KW" });
        brukerList.Add(new Bruker { BrukerID = "15", Passord = "iamlorde", Forbruk = "63KW" });
        brukerList.Add(new Bruker { BrukerID = "16", Passord = "iamlorde", Forbruk = "71KW" });
        brukerList.Add(new Bruker { BrukerID = "17", Passord = "iamlorde", Forbruk = "1KW" });

        ServerStart objSTart = new ServerStart();
        Thread objTraad = new Thread(new ThreadStart(objSTart.Start));

        objTraad.Start();
        while (!objTraad.IsAlive)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            string txt_ut = objSTart.TxtUt();
            TxtUt(txt_ut);
        }



    }
        public void TxtUt(string ct)
        {
            txtConsol.AppendText(ct);

        }
}
}
```

Comment: you can't update the UI directly from another thread, i think in WPF you use `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: txtConsol is a UI control?  If so that is no no.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, you can use the Dispatcher to effect changes on UI items from a separate thread. This is the basic form you'd use:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(()=>{
    yourTextBox.Text = // your value;
    Console.WriteLine(yourTextBox.Text);
}));
```

If for some reason you're unsure whether you're on the UI thread or a separate thread, you can use Dispatcher.CheckAccess(), which will return true if you're on the UI thread and false if you're on a separate thread.

```
if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) {
```

Note that DispatcherPriority requires using the System.Windows.Threading namespace.

Comment: My previous answer only works for winforms... @furkle has a better answer.

Comment: @MikeH Thanks, just didn't want anyone to get confused. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this in WPF, so feel free to top me on this one.

Comment: No problem, glad you brought it up.  I don't do too much WPF, so I'm not sure I can provide a better answer.  I mistakenly assumed that the winform method worked.

Comment: Still a little lost, sorry! Where would you put this in the code?

Comment: @TomasRoaldsnes Anywhere you'd want to alter a UI element. Basically, just wrap any code that's being run on a non-UI thread, but alters an object created on the UI thread, with the first and fourth lines. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

While in code which runs in thread different from main thread, all code that access ui controls should be wrapped in this.Invoke(delegate() {... } )